# Generating multiple pdfs in Excel: possibility to automate?

Tags: excel, pdf, automation

In Excel, I have two sheets, one is raw data, another one is a report template that does `=vlookup` from the first sheet and fills it up with the relevant data. I need to automate the process of generating multiple pdfs of the second sheet (report), each with different data (report1 = data from Sheet1/Row1, report2 = data from Sheet1/Row2, etc.). Any ideas on how is it possible? Alternatively, is it easier to do with different software? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These are the values used on the "Data" sheet

```
1   Bill    Jones       53
2   Steve   Smith       23
3   Greg    Peterson    18
```

The layout on the "Report" sheet

```
Column A    Column B
First       =VLOOKUP(1, Data!A1:D3, 2)
Last        =VLOOKUP(1, Data!A1:D3, 3)
Age         =VLOOKUP(1, Data!A1:D3, 4)
```

The vba code that updates the vlookup equation and then prints the PDF

```
Sub Create_Report()

    Sheets("Report").Select

    For i = 1 To 3
        ' Update vlookup equation
        Range("B1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(" & i & ", Data!RC[-1]:R[2]C[2], 2)"
        Range("B2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(" & i & ", Data!R[-1]C[-1]:R[1]C[2], 3)"
        Range("B3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(" & i & ", Data!R[-2]C[-1]:RC[2], 4)"

        ' Make PDF version of report sheet
        Create_PDF Sheets("Report"), "Report" & i & ".pdf"
    Next i
End Sub

' Code taken from
'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834871%28v=office.11%29.aspx
Sub Create_PDF(Myvar As Object, FixedFilePathName As String)

    'Test to see if the Microsoft Create/Send add-in is installed.
    If Dir(Environ("commonprogramfiles") & "\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE" _
         & Format(Val(Application.Version), "00") & "\EXP_PDF.DLL") <> "" Then

        'Now export the PDF file.
        On Error Resume Next
        Myvar.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=FixedFilePathName, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterPublish
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```

You can call this code directly, use buttons in Excel, or call the macros from another programming language to automate it further.

This was tested on Excel 2013.

FWIW - the Create_Report code was based on a macro that was recorded of the manual steps involved in updating the vlookup values.  The record macro feature is a big help in figuring out how to automate Excel.